# Facebook Messenger Platform Webhooks Post

Tags: facebook, webhooks, messenger

i'm working on facebook messenger platform integration. I setup a webhook but it does not send a post for last 30 minute, why cant i get request?

Developer Facebook => [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKmjp.png

My API => [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOE5A.png

Comment: 1. Your webhook setup indicator shows that it's properly set up and 2. you've correctly subscribed to the page (Axa Social Media Test Page).
So...Can you show what the Receiver log?

Comment: did you generate a token for that page in the "token generation" section and add the callback url in the webhooks (left panel) section?

Comment: Yes i did, i dont remember my problem now :) thank you for your comment :)